# в какой-то момент данные становятся undefined после установки состояния через хук Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю react самостоятельно. поясните пожалуйста, из-за чего происходит такая ситуация. 
PS: заранее извините меня за "многабукаф", пытался максимально понятно объяснить проблему. спасибо.
Суть дела:
Устанавливаю начальное состояние через хук:

```
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({
    img: "",
    name: "",
    types: [],
    abilities: [],
    moveList: [],
    weight: "",
    height: "",
    description: "",
    genus: "",
    chanceToCatch: "",
    evolutionURL: ""
  });
```

далее делаю запросы api для получения информации с помощью useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await Axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: urlPokemonAPI
      })
        .then(result => {
          const pokemonResponse = result.data;

          /* Pokemon Information */
          const img = pokemonResponse.sprites.front_default;
          const name = pokemonResponse.name;
          const weight = Math.round(pokemonResponse.weight / 10);
          const height = pokemonResponse.height / 10;
          const types = pokemonResponse.types.map(type => type.type.name);
          const abilities = pokemonResponse.abilities.map(
            ability => ability.ability.name
          );
          const moveList = pokemonResponse.moves.map(move => move.move.name);
          setPokemon(() => {
            return {
              img: img,
              name: name,
              weight: weight,
              types: types,
              abilities: abilities,
              moveList: moveList,
              height: height
            };
          });
        })

      await Axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: urlPokemonSpecies
      }).then(result => {
        let description = "";
        result.data.flavor_text_entries.some(flavor => {
          if (flavor.language.name === "en") {
            description = flavor.flavor_text;
          }
          return description;
        });
        let genus = "";
        result.data.genera.some(genera => {
          if (genera.language.name === "en") {
            genus = genera.genus;
          }
          return genus;
        });
        const evolutionURL = result.data.evolution_chain.url;
        const eggGroups = result.data.egg_groups.map(
          egg_group => egg_group.name
        );
        const chanceToCatch = Math.round(
          (result.data.capture_rate * 100) / 255
        );
        setPokemon(pokemon => {
          return {
            ...pokemon,
            description: description,
            genus: genus,
            chanceToCatch: chanceToCatch,
            evolutionURL: evolutionURL,
            eggGroups: eggGroups
          };
        });
      });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [urlPokemonAPI, urlPokemonSpecies]);
```

Проблема возникает конкретно с `eggGroups`(с идентичной обработкой `abilities` и `types` такой проблемы нет). А происходит вот что, когда я хочу вывести данные на страницу как `<div>Egg Group: {pokemon.eggGroups}</div>` данные выводятся нормально, но как только я хочу вывести как `abilities` и `types` через запятую, возникает ошибка `TypeError: pokemon.eggGroups is undefined`. Решил я это дело проверить через консоль и запихнул этот ключ `eggGroups` в таймаут.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В какой-то момент `eggGroups` становится undefined... почему, не могу понять. Но если установлю состояние отдельно, как const `[egg, setEgg] = useState([]); setEgg(eggGroups);` такой проблемы не наблюдается. из-за чего так происходит? с `types` и `abilities` было все нормально. 
Заранее благодарю.

**UDP!!! 
Вопрос разрешен.** Проблема заключалась вот в чем: когда я обновлял стейт первый раз:

```
setPokemon(() => {
        return {
          ....
        };
      });
```

я перезаписывал все, что было объявлено в `const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({ ... })`. а затем когда я ниже опять обращался к стейту

```
setPokemon(pokemon => {return { ...pokemon, ...}});
```

как раз в нем я обращался к ключу `eggGroups: eggGroups`, но ключа `eggGroups` уже не было.
Закину обновленный вариант кода, может быть кому-нибудь пригодится

```
import Axios from "axios";

const Pokemon = props => {
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({
    img: "",
    name: "",
    weight: "",
    height: "",
    description: "",
    genus: "",
    types: [],
    abilities: [],
    moveList: [],
    eggGroups: [],
    stats: {},
    chanceToCatch: "",
    evolutionURL: ""
  });

  const pokemonNameForAPI = props.match.params.pokemonName.toLowerCase();
  const urlPokemonAPI = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonNameForAPI}/`;
  const urlPokemonSpeciesAPI = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/${pokemonNameForAPI}/`;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const resultPokemonAPI = await Axios.get(urlPokemonAPI);
        const dataPokemonAPI = resultPokemonAPI.data;
        const resultPokemonSpeciesAPI = await Axios.get(urlPokemonSpeciesAPI);
        const dataPokemonSpeciesAPI = resultPokemonSpeciesAPI.data;

        /* Pokemon Information */
        const img = dataPokemonAPI.sprites.front_default;
        const name = dataPokemonAPI.name;
        const weight = Math.round(dataPokemonAPI.weight / 10); // hectograms->kilogram
        const height = dataPokemonAPI.height / 10; // decimeters->meters
        function getDescription(data) {
          let result = "";
          data.flavor_text_entries.forEach(flavor => {
            if (flavor.language.name === "en") {
              result = flavor.flavor_text;
            }
          });
          return result;
        }
        const description = getDescription(dataPokemonSpeciesAPI);
        function getGenus(data) {
          let result = "";
          data.genera.forEach(genera => {
            if (genera.language.name === "en") {
              result = genera.genus;
            }
          });
          return result;
        }
        const genus = getGenus(dataPokemonSpeciesAPI);
        const types = dataPokemonAPI.types.map(type => type.type.name);
        const abilities = dataPokemonAPI.abilities.map(
          ability => ability.ability.name
        );
        const moveList = dataPokemonAPI.moves.map(move => move.move.name);
        function getStats(data) {
          const result = {};
          data.stats.map(stat => {
            result[stat.stat.name] = stat.base_stat; // add keys: speed, special-defense, special-attack, attack, hp
          });
          return result;
        }
        const stats = getStats(dataPokemonAPI);
        const eggGroups = dataPokemonSpeciesAPI.egg_groups.map(
          egg_group => egg_group.name
        );
        const chanceToCatch = Math.round(
          (dataPokemonSpeciesAPI.capture_rate * 100) / 255 // 255/100=dataPokemonSpeciesAPI.capture_rate/x
        );
        const evolutionURL = dataPokemonSpeciesAPI.evolution_chain.url;
        /* ****** */

        /* update State */
        setPokemon(prev => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            img: img,
            name: name,
            weight: weight,
            height: height,
            description: description,
            genus: genus,
            types: types,
            abilities: abilities,
            moveList: moveList,
            eggGroups: eggGroups,
            stats: stats,
            chanceToCatch: chanceToCatch,
            evolutionURL: evolutionURL
          };
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [urlPokemonAPI, urlPokemonSpeciesAPI]);
```

Answer (score 0):

О это типичные грабли на которые наступает каждый )
Внимательно посмотри на все вызовы setState() каждый должен содержать ...state

Comment: да, благодарю за коммент. я уже нашел проблему еще раньше, все никак не дойду чтобы тут выложить обновленный вариант, вдруг кому-нибудь пригодится. да и вы правы, проблема со state, когда я вызываю его второй раз там и происходит ошибка. все равно благодарю за коммент еще раз!